# How can I reuse a hardcoded array of data in multiple angular 1.5 controllers?

Tags: angularjs, reusability

I have two angular controllers that both have this:

```
var data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
```

How can I have that in one place instead of two and reuse it in each controller?

Comment: Have it in service and access it through calling service from both controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do that is by using the `value` or `constant` [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), they were designed to do that. Then you can inject this on any of other provider declaration that you have (i.e., `directive`, `component`, `controller`, etc).

```
myApp.value('MyData', ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']);

myApp.controller('myController', function (MyData) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.data = MyData;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service that contains a method that returns the array

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    var data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

    this.getData= function () {
        return data;
    }
});
```

And call it inside your controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.getData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This array is simple model-data representation, and you should put it in to service (service is singleton, and in each controller you have access to same array).

Simple example:

```
app.factory('myArray', 
  function() {
    this.array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
    return this.array;
  });
```

In each controller you can access this array:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myArray) {
    $scope.array = myArray;
});
```

Plunker example available https://plnkr.co/edit/m307rP4IjcXSJpPWmHeA?p=info